# ElasticSearch - Search for value on nested object under any key

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have documents indexed in ES with the following structure:

doc 1:

```json
{
 "map": {
   "field1": ["foo"],
   "field2": ["bar"]
 }
}
```

doc2

```json
{
 "map": {
   "fieldN": ["foo"],
 }
}
```

I need to search all the documents that match a specific value under any key in the "map" object. Since the fields in "map" are dynamic, the value can be found under any key.

I tried different queries but none of them seems to work since it looks like for all the cases, I need to specify the field explicitly (ex.: map.field1 = "foo")

I would hope to be able to do a search like this:

```json
{ 
  "fields": ["map.*"], 
  "query": "foo" 
}
```

Any recommendations on how to approach this type of search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), to search for a query term on `map.*` fields

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "foo", 
      "fields": [ "map.*" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually tested "multi_match" but for some reason I am getting mixed results. 
I get documents that match the query value I am looking for and also documents where the value doesn't even exist in the document.
I wonder if I need to map the fields in a specific way to make it work.

Comment: I found the issue. After adding ".keyword" to the query value, the documents I get are the correct ones.